# How to encode json in Java?

Tags: java, php, json

My Java client has to encode values as Json (using the equivalent of php's `json_encode`), so that a remote PHP server can open it up with `json_decode`.  What built in method and library should be used for this encoding?

Comment: Look at google GSON (reliable). There are other json libraries but I have found the two others I tested to be unreliable

Comment: how can the question be downvoted and the answer upvoted? there's clearly a bit of a disconnect here !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing JSon is not so hard. You can concatenate strings, ...

Or you can use JSONObject:

```
Map<String,String> mss=new HashMap<String,String>();
mss.put("France", "Paris");
mss.put("Germany", "Berlin");

JSONObject j=new JSONObject(mss);

System.out.println(j);
```

you can also put some datas like that:

```
j.put("one key", "one value");
```

there are also array:  JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

I have used "Jackson Faster API" for java to Json and json to java conversion. It is pretty easy to implemented. So far no issues. mapping for Composite java objects also available.